# How to get all max count with a field

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am trying to return the names with the max number of entries in a table and return a list of (name, count) tuples for those with the max for count. My current solution uses:

```
select name, count(*)
from action_log
group by name
order by count desc
limit 1;
```

The problem is that using `limit 1` does not account for multiple names having a max count value.

How can I determine the max count and then get ALL matching names? I want to (but can't obviously) do something like:

```
select name, max(count(*))
from action_log
group by name;
```

Comment: To clarify, you're looking for the person that comes up the most, right?

Comment: wouldn't you just add an `ORDER BY COUNT` line to the sql statement?

Comment: @Elias The "people" that come up the most. Sometimes there are multiple users with the same count that is simultaneously the max count.

Comment: @tigeravatar There is an order by count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/09cca/1)

```
with s as (
    select name, count(*) as total
    from action_log
    group by name
), m as (
    select max(total) as max_total from s
)
select name, total
from s
where total = (select max_total from m)
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with sub queries - except there are some rules surrounding the group by. How about simplifying it with a view:

```
create view cname as
    select name, count(name) c
    from action_log
    group by name
```

and then `SELECT` like this:

```
select distinct a.name
from action_log a
  join cname c on c.name = a.name
where c.c = (select max(c) from cname)
```

and here is a [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a034f/6/0) to prove it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select name, COUNT(*)
from action_log
group by name
HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT TOP 1 COUNT(*) from action_log group by name ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with subquery

For example:

```
SELECT MAX(cnt) FROM
(SELECT name, count(*) AS cnt
FROM action_log
GROUP BY name) AS gb
```

Comment: I get `column "n" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function.` when I run this.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with [rank()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html) function, so you don't have to query table multiple times:

```
with cte as (
    select
        name, count(*) as total,
        rank() over(order by count(*) desc) as rnk
    from action_log
    group by name
)
select name, total
from cte
where rnk = 1
```

Even better, you can [dense_rank()](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-window.html), so you can take n groups or take nth group:

```
with cte as (
    select
        name, count(*) as total,
        dense_rank() over(order by count(*) desc) as rnk
    from action_log
    group by name
)
select name, total
from cte
where rnk <= 2 -- or rnk in (1, 2), or rnk = 2 and so on
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/877df/2)</kbd>**